# Substitute string with Python Template strings method

Tags: python, string, substitution

I would like to use Template strings to substitute strings in a path to a temporary file:

```
from string import Template

expanded = Template('/tmp/hive_perf_test/$table_table_$rows').substitute(rows = THE_ROWS, table = THE_TABLE)
```

Unfortunately, I could replace only `$rows` when trying to `$table`, I got this error message:

```
{KeyError}'table_table_'
```

Comment: What library sis `Template` from?

Comment: I'm guessing that you expect `$table` to be substituted, but Python thinks that you want `$table_table` to be substituted.

Comment: Can you post what you have in `**cfg` ?

Comment: Simple hack, change `idpattern` from default `[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*` to e.g. `[a-z][a-z0-9]*` to tell python that `_` is end of template variable name

Comment: Or you can use `${table}_table_${rows}`

Comment: Teplate ist imported from the Library string: from string import Template

Comment: **cfg is a dictionary:

Answer (score 0):

For python tempate strings underscore is considered as part of the identifier. Change `'/tmp/hive_perf_test/$table_table_$rows'`  to `'/tmp/hive_perf_test/${table}_table_$rows'` , *add curly braces around table*, and your are good to go.